# Add multiple rows in just one row from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, view

How can I join multiple rows in just one single row through mysql?

Example :

Student Table

```
Sno.| Name  |  Subjects
1.  | ABC   |  English
2.  | ABC   |  Mathematics
3.  | ABC   |  Science
4.  | FMC |  French
5.  | ABC   |  Russian
6.  | JBC   |  French
```

Now I want it in this format

```
Sno.| Name |   Sub1 |  Sub2 | Sub3 |  Sub4 |
1.  | ABC |   Eng  |  Maths| Science| Russian
2.  | FMC |    French| Null| Null   | Null
3.  | JBC |   French| Null | Null   | Null
```

I am not sure how to actually do it? And shall I create a view or a table?

I guess a view will be fine.

Comment: Do you really need separate columns? Otherwise you could use `GROUP_CONCAT`. And what do you want to do with that data afterwards?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: i want to make reports in pdf by fpdf.

Comment: @IPerfect : For printing in pdf, which language you are using?

Comment: @FahimParkar for the pdf, i use PHP and FPDF.

Comment: @IPerfect : Please check my answer and let me know if you have any queries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the other answers, that `GROUP_CONCAT` along with PHP to split the comma separated values is probably the best approach, however if for any other reason you needed the output you suggested via Pure SQL I would suggest one of the following appoaches.

**[1. Self Joins](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f738c/3)**

```
SELECT  t1.Name, 
        MIN(t1.Subject) AS Sub1,
        MIN(t2.Subject) AS Sub2,
        MIN(t3.Subject) AS Sub3,
        MIN(t4.Subject) AS Sub4
FROM    Students t1
        LEFT JOIN Students T2 
            ON t1.Name = t2.Name 
            AND t2.Subject > t1.Subject
        LEFT JOIN Students T3 
            ON t2.Name = t3.Name 
            AND t3.Subject > t2.Subject
        LEFT JOIN Students T4 
            ON t3.Name = t4.Name 
            AND t4.Subject > t3.Subject
GROUP BY t1.Name;
```

**[2. Using a ROW_NUMBER Type function to aggregate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f738c/12)**

```
SELECT   Name,
         MAX(IF(RowNum = 1,Subject, NULL)) AS Sub1,
         MAX(IF(RowNum = 2,Subject, NULL)) AS Sub2,
         MAX(IF(RowNum = 3,Subject, NULL)) AS Sub3,
         MAX(IF(RowNum = 4,Subject, NULL)) AS Sub4
FROM     (    SELECT   Name,
                       Subject,
                       @r:= IF(@Name = Name, @r + 1, 1) AS RowNum,
                       @Name:= Name AS Name2
              FROM    Students,
                      (SELECT @Name:='') n,
                      (SELECT @r:= 0) r
              ORDER BY Name, Sno
          ) t
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Using below query, get the Name and his/ her subjects.

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Subjects) AS List
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Then in PHP, you can use **[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** function for printing subjects.

Hope this helps.

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f108/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY and [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Subjects) AS Subjects_list
FROM students_table
GROUP BY Name
```

Then use PHP function [explode](http://php.net/explode) while fetching records to get the different values stored in Subjects_list column.

Comment: Hmmm, let me check. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty!

To use the above solutions, you could do:

```
SELECT 
  Sno, 
  Name,
  NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(all_subjects, ',', 1), ',', -1), '') AS Sub1,
  NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(all_subjects, ',', 2), ',', -1), '') AS Sub2,
  NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(all_subjects, ',', 3), ',', -1), '') AS Sub3,
  NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(all_subjects, ',', 4), ',', -1), '') AS Sub4
FROM (
  SELECT Sno, Name, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(Subjects ORDER BY Sno),',,,') AS all_subjects FROM table GROUP BY name
) inner_sel
;
```

Your requests leads to the assumption there can be never more than **4** subjects. You also require `NULL`s where there is no mention of four subjects.

There kind of requests lead to a forced SQL code, one which is typically what SQL is intended for.

To explain the above: we use `GROUP_CONCAT`, then break it again to pieces. Since there could be fewer than **4** elements, we pad with commas (`',,,'`). We then break each piece according to its place within the concatenated string, and return with `NULL` if it's empty.

Can't say this is one of my better answers in terms of prettiness. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: can i create a view with this?

Comment: You'll have to create two views, because of the derived table. So, a view for the inner SELECT, another that reads from it.